# Split application windows to fit the screen

Tags: window-management

I just want to split apps to divide the screen in two or three like the image below

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Luís de Sousa](https://askubuntu.com/users/177437/lu%c3%ads-de-sousa) answered [on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586424/how-do-i-display-two-windows-as-split-screen/586427#586427):

> To set a window occupying the left half of the screen use this shortcut:
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + [<kbd>Super</kbd>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys) + <kbd>←</kbd>
>
> For the right half:
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + [<kbd>Super</kbd>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19558/what-are-the-meta-super-and-hyper-keys) + <kbd>→</kbd>

<kbd>Super</kbd> is the Windows key.

Comment: It would be great, but does not work for my windows 10.

Answer (score 6):

If you drag the windows to either corner of the screen, they will snap into place. To snap them back to their original size just click and drag away from the side of the screen again.

Comment: I understand, but it kind of tedious, that's why I'm asking. But thanks buddy!

Comment: I don't understand, what is tedious about that?

Comment: @RolandiXor most OSes have a shortcut - like Ubuntu GNOME has Super + Arrow.

Comment: `super + arrow` is the shortcut for the multi-tasking desktop changer so it won't work but i would surely like this feature

Comment: I am just saying about a shorcut that allow me to do it

Comment: @mallorca so you assumed we would read your mind and figure this out without any mention of the keyboard in your question :)?

Comment: Ups.. Sorry. haha