# Split Application windows to fit Screen

Tags: window-management

I can do Ctrl-Super- < or > but it doesn't allow me to do 2 windows. Nor when I drag a window (instead of using the keyboard) to the left or right side, it doesn't automatically adjust itself.

[Split application windows to fit the screen](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/314/split-application-windows-to-fit-the-screen/315#315)

Answer (score 1):

> I can do Ctrl-Super- < or > but it doesn't allow me to do 2 windows.

You have to focus the 2nd window before.
You can do that by click on the window or using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

> Nor when I drag a window (instead of using the keyboard) to the left or right side, it doesn't automatically adjust itself.

Did you tried that with different windows?
Maybe it just don't work with a special window that isn't allowed to be resized.